# Before signout perform some action in rails using omniauthentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am using devise and omni authentication for authentication from twitter. My sign out is working i want to trigger some background job before signet action has been performed how can i do that ?

Comment: You can override Devise `Devise::SessionsController` and create one method and call it in before action block which will run only when destroy seession action get called

Comment: Thank you replying but i am not using devise sessions i am using ominauth which is also integrated with devise.

Comment: this is what it represents in routes for logout but i am not able to figure out where is this file and where ti edit it. ```get "logout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout```

Comment: can you pls check log and see which controller and action get called on sign out.

Comment: i m pretty much sure its Devise::SessionsController's destroy action

Comment: Yes its same :) but where can i find this action in my app?

Comment: Or do i have to change it in devise gem ?

Comment: no u dont need to change in devise gem. u just have to create one new sessions controller which will be inherited from Devise::SessionsController

Comment: Okay thank you will try and let you know :)